Jacobian determinant of a function defined by an embedding, transformation, then projection
I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^D$ which I know is invertible (i.e. positive, nonzero Jacobian determinant). I do not know what this function is but I have $N>D$ points from this function (i.e. $\left\lbrace(x_i,y_i)\right\rbrace_{i=1:N}$ where $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^D$ and $y_i=f(x_i)\in \mathbb{R}^D$). I want to approximate this function in the following way. Create and embedding $E: \mathbb{R}^D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ ($u=E(x)$), a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ ($v=T(u)$), and a projection $P:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^D$ ($y=P(v)$). I then fit $(P\circ T\circ E)(x_i)= y_i$ as the approximation to my function, $f$. I need to be able to compute the Jacobian determinant of this approximation and ensure it is also invertible. I have a few questions on this
A) How do I compute the Jacobian determinant of this approximation? By the chain rule, the Jacobian is
$J_{P\circ T\circ E}(x) = J_P( (T\circ E)(x))\cdot J_T(E(x)) \cdot J_E(x)$
To compute the determinant, I would normally break it apart as
$det\left|J_P( (T\circ E)(x))\cdot J_T(E(x)) \cdot J_E(x)\right|=det\left|J_P( (T\circ E)(x))\right|\cdot det\left|J_T(E(x))\right| \cdot det\left|J_E(x)\right|$
But the above does not hold since $J_E(x)\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times D}$ and $J_P( (T\circ E)(x))\in\mathbb{R}^{D\times N}$ aren't square matrices. Is there an efficient method or identity to compute this determinant?
B) Are there assumptions I can make on the structure of the functions to make the computation of the determinant easier? For example, for a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$, if it is a triangular, then $det\left|A\right|=\prod_i^N a_{ii}$.
C) Is this a known method for function approximations, or something relatively similar?
